# Django Error: from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: django

I'm using django and virtual environment "virtualenv", activate it, try to run the server in the project folder like this: python manage.py runserver, but I get this error: from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'.

what could be happening? if someone can help, thank you in advance

Comment: Is **Django** installed in your env ? (`pip install django`) If yes, please try again from scratch using this steps : https://www.javatpoint.com/django-virtual-environment-setup

Answer (score 1):

First go to the terminal and write pipenv shell he must return for you a file url if he doesn't you must write it again then copy the file url in the bottom of visual studio you will find a place called 3.9.6 or your version (and here he writes for you the name of the project ) click on this place a popup menu will be shown click on error interpreter path then paste the link then click enter and your problem will be solved

Comment: Thank you for your support but it does not work

Comment: In the bottom of visual study code you could click on select interpetor then click python 3.9.13 and I hope I helped you